# How to set Onclick listener to dynamic spinner item

Tags: java, android

I have three spinners (1.Vehicle make, 2.Vehicle Type, 3.Model). Vehicle make having only option "2 Wheeler","4 Wheeler".

What i did, If i choosed anyone  option from vehicle make means shows only that type of vehicle type(For ex: If i choose 2 Wheeler means Vehicle Type shows Bajaj,Honda etc., like this).

I want, If i choose anyone option from vehicle type means show that type of model in third spinner.

I dont know how to access/change third spinner when second spinner selected.

Please anyone help me!

My code here:

```js
public class VehicleFragment extends Fragment {

 Spinner vehicleType;
 Spinner vehicleMake;
 Spinner model;

 String[] vehicleItems = {"Please Choose Vehicle Type","2 Wheeler","4 Wheeler"};
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_vehicle, container,
                false);

        vehicleType = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.veh_typeSpinner);
        vehicleMake = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.makeSpinner);
        model = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.modelSpinner);

  //VehicleType adapter
  ArrayAdapter vehicleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,vehicleItems);
  vehicleAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        vehicleType.setAdapter(vehicleAdapter);
        vehicleType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new VehiclTypeSelectedListener());

        return view;
    }

    public class VehiclTypeSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            if (item == "2 Wheeler"){
                addItemOnVehicleMake();
            }
            else if (item == "4 Wheeler"){
                addItemOnFourVehicleMake();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }


    }

    public void addItemOnVehicleMake(){

        vehicleMake = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.makeSpinner);
        String[] myState = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.twoWheeler_make);
        List<String> makeArrayList = Arrays.asList(myState);
        ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, makeArrayList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        vehicleMake.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    public void addItemOnFourVehicleMake(){

        vehicleMake = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.makeSpinner);
        String[] myState = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fourWheeler_make);
        List<String> makeArrayList = Arrays.asList(myState);
        ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, makeArrayList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        vehicleMake.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you need to implement a custom adapter and in the getView of the adapter before returning the view set the onClickListeners to whichever View you want there.

Comment: keep your data in sqlite db, it will make your life a lot easier: all you need is just one sqlite db query

Comment: Im very new for android.. Could you tell any easy way to do that

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 0):

Get the child of layout and check instance of spinner then set onClick listenet.

Answer (score 0):

When addItemOnVehicleMake() method called, at that time suppose "vehicleMake" spinner has vehicle make companies like,

```
        Bajaj, 
        Honda,
        .
        . etc,
```

and inside addItemOnFourVehicleMake() method 4-wheeler has,

```
        Honda,
        Ford,
        .
        .. etc.
```

When populate spinner it always set first value from list by default unless we set different item position manually.

```
If two wheeler has set Bajaj, get list of models of Bajaj and populate spinner of "VehicleMake" inside addItemOnVehicleMake() for the first item only.

            public void addItemOnVehicleMake()
            {
               ...
               ... 
               // code here to bind model spinner and set default "0" position item.
               model.setSelection(0);
            }

    Also write down the VehicleMake spinner item select listener method,to populate the "VehicleModel" spinner based on selected item in "VehicleMake" spinner.

    vehicleMake.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            //Here is the code to populate model spinner.
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: I didn't understand.. where i can place that above code. Could you edit my code

Comment: Put the spinner onItemSelectListener in onCreateview(). Inside addItemOnVehicleMake() and addItemOnFourVehicleMake() put the code to default model population.

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate your spinner at the time when say you choose "2 Wheeler". For this you need to have data sets of vehicles that are 2 wheelers and a separate dataset for vehicles that are say 4 wheelers. 
So basically in your addItemOnVehicleMake(String s) method, send your item string to this method:

```
public void addItemOnFourVehicleMake(String vehicleType){
    if(vehicleType == "4 Wheeler"){
   //add dataset to spinner that shows only 4 wheelers.
}
else if(vehicleType == "2 Wheeler"){
   //add dataset to spinner that shows only 2 wheelers.
}
//and so on....
}
```